# Need help using JFileChooser to import entire folder into JList in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlist, jfilechooser

I'm in the middle of creating a small program. I'm a bit of a noob when it       comes to programming and I just starting playing with the NetBeans GUI builder to help out a friend with his code. So far what happens is:

1. JFrame pops up with a non-editable text field, button, JList, and empty panel.
2. User clicks button, and it prompts them to select a directory.
3. Once the user selects the directory, the program will load all files from this folder (eventually I'll set it to only allow .jpg).
4. The program will then display the directory in the text field and place the names of these files in the JList.

   PROBLEM: 
   I'm having trouble with 4. I've been trying forever to get this thing to run. I've     gotten it to display the directory correctly. But I can't seem to get the JList to load the   file names from a file array. Here's some code if anyone can help. 
   *NOTE*: I have already declared a DefaulListModel named listModel outside of this buttons action event. The code isn't generating any errors but the JList remains empty after I click load. 
   text field -> directory 
   button -> jButton1 
   file chooser -> fc 
   string array of file names -> fileNames 
   file array of -> selectedFiles 
   JList -> fileList

   Thanks in advance! :)

   ```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); 
   fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
   fc.showOpenDialog(null);
   File[] selectedFiles = fc.getSelectedFiles();
   directory.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); //this displays the path of the selected folder in the text field

   selectedFiles = fc.getSelectedFiles();        
   //this loop puts the files in the fileList... at least it should
   for(int i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++){
       listModel.addElement(selectedFiles[i]);
               }


   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JFileChooser` is set to only allow to select directories. I assume that

```
selectedFiles = fc.getSelectedFiles();
```

returns an empty array, which would explain why you do not see anything in your list.

You probably want to replace it by

```
File directory = fc.getSelectedFile();
if ( directory != null && directory.isDirectory() ){
  File[] subFiles = directory.listFiles();
  for ( int i = 0; i < subFiles.length; i++ ){
    listModel.addElement( subFiles[i] );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I would never have figured this out on my own. So if I'm not mistaken, the problem was that I was trying to load a file, but the folder was the only thing selected, causing it to return null?

Comment: It returns an empty array when your file chooser is in single selection mode according to the javadoc. But just use a debugger and check the return value